# Async/Await in high-scale projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

Is using Async/Await in calling every database methods(Repository Pattern) in a large and high scale project, ok?
Is it going to lower my server performance?
Sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is using Async/Await in calling every database methods(Repository Pattern) in a large and high scale project, ok?

Yes.

> Is it going to lower my server performance?

The speed of each individual request will remain approximately the same. However, the *scalability* of your sever will increase (become more performant), assuming that your database backend is also scalable.

Answer (score 2):

The performance of your server does not depend on whether the calls are synchronous or asynchronous, but it does depend on how many calls are made at the same time (concurrency) and of course the hardware or resources available to the server.

Comment: "does not depend on whether the calls are synchronous or asynchronous" actually [it probably does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-6.0#avoid-blocking-calls)

Comment: Yes if use that methods: Block asynchronous execution by calling Task.Wait or Task<TResult>.Result.  It would not make any sense to call .Wait() or .Result() because with that you are making the code synchronous. But if you use the async/await pattern correctly, you won't have that problem.